# Pig Performance Issues

Tags: performance, hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

I have following PIG script which is taking lot of time for processing 342 files with 256 MB as split size(testing only). Can anybody suggest improvement:

```
SPLIT filteredalnumcdrs into splitalnumcdrs_1 IF (
            (SUBSTRING(aparty,2,3) == '-')),
            splitalnumcdrs_2 OTHERWISE;

tmpsplitalnumcdrs_1 = FOREACH splitalnumcdrs_1 GENERATE aparty,srcgt,destgt,SUBSTRING(aparty,0,2) as splitaparty,bparty,smscgt,status,prepost;

groupsplitalnumcdrs_1 = GROUP tmpsplitalnumcdrs_1 BY (aparty,srcgt,destgt,splitaparty,bparty,smscgt,status,prepost);

distinctsplitalnumcdrs_1 = FOREACH groupsplitalnumcdrs_1 {
    uniqsplitalnumcdrs_1 = DISTINCT tmpsplitalnumcdrs_1.(aparty,srcgt,destgt,splitaparty,bparty,smscgt,status,prepost);
    GENERATE FLATTEN(group),COUNT(tmpsplitalnumcdrs_1) as countalnumcdrs;
    };

tmpsplitalnumcdrs_2 = FOREACH splitalnumcdrs_2 GENERATE aparty,srcgt,destgt,aparty as splitaparty_2,bparty,smscgt,status,prepost;
groupsplitalnumcdrs_2 = GROUP tmpsplitalnumcdrs_2 BY (aparty,srcgt,destgt,splitaparty_2,bparty,smscgt,status,prepost);

distinctsplitalnumcdrs_2 = FOREACH groupsplitalnumcdrs_2 {
    uniqsplitalnumcdrs_2 = DISTINCT tmpsplitalnumcdrs_2.(aparty,srcgt,destgt,splitaparty_2,bparty,smscgt,status,prepost);
    GENERATE FLATTEN(group),COUNT(tmpsplitalnumcdrs_2) as countsplitalnumcdrs_2;
    };

distinctalnumcdrs = UNION distinctsplitalnumcdrs_1,distinctsplitalnumcdrs_2;

alnumreportmap = FOREACH distinctalnumcdrs GENERATE aparty,smsiuc_udfs.mapgtabparty(srcgt,destgt,splitaparty,bparty),smscgt,status,prepost,countalnumcdrs PARALLEL 20;
alnumreportmapgroup = GROUP alnumreportmap BY (aparty,mappedreport,smscgt,status,prepost);
alnumreportmaprecord = FOREACH alnumreportmapgroup GENERATE FLATTEN(group),SUM(alnumreportmap.countalnumcdrs) as alnumsmscount;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can avoid union

```
tmpsplitalnumcdrs = foreach filteredalnumcdrs generate aparty,srcgt,destgt,(SUBSTRING(aparty,2,3) == '-' ?SUBSTRING(aparty,0,2):aparty)  as splitaparty,bparty,smscgt,status,prepost;

distinctsplitalnumcdrs = FOREACH tmpsplitalnumcdrs {
uniqsplitalnumcdrs = DISTINCT tmpsplitalnumcdrs.(aparty,srcgt,destgt,splitaparty,bparty,smscgt,status,prepost);
GENERATE FLATTEN(group),COUNT(tmpsplitalnumcdrs) as countsplitalnumcdrs;
};
```

why do you need

```
uniqsplitalnumcdrs = DISTINCT tmpsplitalnumcdrs.(aparty,srcgt,destgt,splitaparty,bparty,smscgt,status,prepost);
```

Comment: but you are not using it right. Inside the group the distinct will be one why are you having it.

Comment: Avoiding UNION gives a good impact. For the distinct, looking at code again seems that `DISTINCT tmpsplitalnumcdrs` will work. Is it or someother catch ??

Comment: i meant you can remove that statement itself as you are not using uniqsplitalnumcdrs. remove statement uniqsplitalnumcdrs = DISTINCT tmpsplitalnumcdrs.(aparty,srcgt,destgt,splitaparty,bparty,smscgt,status,prepost);

Comment: you are correct, but i need the distinct row along with its count. Say for 100 total count of `filteredalnumcdrs `, the row count for `distinctsplitalnumcdrs` say is 52, then each row of `distinctsplitalnumcdrs` must contain the count field which on summing comes out to be 100.

Comment: but where are you using uniqsplitalnumcdrs  it is local to foreach you cant use it outside?

Comment: So need to group and then foreach. `groupsplitalnumcdrs = GROUP tmpsplitalnumcdrs BY (aparty,srcgt,destgt,splitaparty,bparty,smscgt,status,prepost);

distinctsplitalnumcdrs = FOREACH groupsplitalnumcdrs {
        GENERATE FLATTEN(group),COUNT(tmpsplitalnumcdrs) as countsplitalnumcdrs;
        };`